# Displaying integers from file on one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the very simple task of creating a text file with 8 random integers from 1-100, reading the file, displaying the numbers on the same line, calculating the even integers and the odd integers, and then displaying them.

The problem I am having is getting the string to display on the same line. I have browsed multiple articles about similar problems to no avail. I have attempted to use .join, however, it seems to break the code when I include it.

```py
# Imports random and time 
import random
import time

# Defines the main function 
def main():

    # Opens file "mynumbers" and creates it if not existent 
    myfile = open('mynumbers.txt', 'w')

    # Statement to write intergers to text file in the correct format
    for count in range(8):
        number = random.randint(1, 100)
        myfile.write(str(number) + '\n')

# Defines read function 
def read():

    # Opens the "mynumbers" file created in the main function 
    myfile= open('mynumbers.txt', 'r')

    # Sets the content variable to the content of the file that was opened 
    content = myfile.read()

    # Prints the content variable and strips the \n from the string
    stripit = content.rstrip('\n')
    print(stripit)


# Calls for the functions, prints created, and sleep calls
main()
print('File Created!')
time.sleep(1)
read()
time.sleep(5)
```

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `read` function is reading the whole file contents into a single string. Your `rstrip` call on that string removes the last newline from it, but not any of the internal newlines. You can't effectively use `str.join`, since you only have the one string.

I think there are two reasonable solutions. The first is to stay with just a single string, but replace all the internal newlines with spaces:

```
def read():
    myfile = open('mynumbers.txt', 'r')
    content = myfile.read()
    stripit = content.rstrip('\n')
    nonewlines = stripit.replace('\n', ' ')
    print(nonewlines)
```

The other approach is to split the single string up into a list of separate strings, one for each number. This is more useful if we need to do different things with them later. Of course, all we're going to do is use `join` to combine them back together:

```
def read():
    myfile = open('mynumbers.txt', 'r')
    content = myfile.read()
    content_list = content.split() # by default, splits on any kind of whitespace
    rejoined_content = " ".join(content_list)
    print(rejoined_content)
```

Comment: Really appreciate it! That first one is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you everyone for all the quick responses!

Answer (score 1):

Don't add a newline char when you write the file. Just use a space instead (or comma, whatever)

```
import random
import time

#Defines the main function
def main():

#Opens file "mynumbers" and creates it if not existent
    myfile = open('mynumbers.txt', 'w')

#Statement to write intergers to text file in the correct format
    for count in range(8):
        number = random.randint(1,100)
        myfile.write(str(number) +' ')

#Defines read function
def read():

#Opens the "mynumbers" file created in the main function
    myfile= open('mynumbers.txt', 'r')

#Sets the content variable to the content of the file that was opened
    content=myfile.read()

#Prints the content variable and strips the \n from the string
    print(content)



#Calls for the functions, prints created, and sleep calls
main()
print('File Created!')
time.sleep(1)
read()
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Although I agree that this is a solution, the point of this program is to convert from \n to a single line so it doesn't work for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

the code looks great but do this instead on your read() function.

```
def read():
     my_numbers = []
     with open('mynumbers.txt', 'r') as infile:
          for line in infile:
               line = line.strip()
               my_numbers.append(line)
     print (' '.join(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, especially because you mentioned the even and odd part that you'll need to do next.  At the end of the first loop, you'll have a list of ints (rather than strs) that you can work with and determine whether they are even or odd.

```
def read():
     my_nums = []
     with open('mynumbers.txt', 'r') as f:
          for line in f:
               num_on_line = int(line.strip())
               my_nums += [num_on_line]
               print num_on_line, #don't forget that comma
     for num in my_nums:
          #display the even and odds
```

Answer (score 0):

You could print the numbers in a single line in this way

```
with open('mynumbers.txt', 'r') as numbers_file:
    for line in numbers_file:
        print(line.strip(), end=" ")
```

The `line.strip()` is for eliminate the `\n` character.